# How to disable JQuery keypress event for just one element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

On my site I have registered a keypress event handler for the whole document.

```
$(document).keypress(myhandler);
```

And I handle the 'space' key to scroll a list.

Trouble is, there is an `<input type='text' />` element, and I don't want 'space' keypress to scroll the list when it is entered in the input.

I couldn't find any information in the "event" object passed by JQuery to the handler, to identify where the source of the event is.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Alternatively, you could attach another event handler to the input field, and in this handler stop the propagation of the event:

```
jQuery('#input-field-id').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

This way, you can leave the global event handler as it is. Might be cleaner.

Comment: Instead of `e.stopPropagation();` use 
`e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 3):

you're looking for `event.target.id`, which will be the id of the element that the event was raised on. So inside `myhandler` you would need something like the following

```
function myhandler(e) {
    if (e.target.id !== 'id of input') {
        /* rest of event handler */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the QuirksMode docs about [event order](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html), and especially about how to turn off the events, which is browser-specific. Quote:

*For a complete cross-browser experience do*

```
function doSomething(e)
{
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
}
```