# jQuery class event handlers - how to disable for one element in class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, event-handling, stoppropagation

I have an event handler attached to a class, as so:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.myClass', function (e) {...
```

Within this handler I want to attach a different click handler to the element that has been clicked. When the temporary handler has been clicked, I want to re-enable the original handler.

What I'm trying to do (as shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vmQ4/2/)) is allow a section of text to be clicked, change that to an input text box, and then submit the change to recreate the text.

I've tried the following without success as found at [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vmQ4/2/):

```
$('#container').on('click', '.submit', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        new_text = $this.prev().val();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $this.parent().off('click.temp').html(new_text);                    
});

$('#container').on('click', '.test', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html("<input type='text' value='" + $this.text() + "'/><input class='submit' value='Submit' type='submit'>");
    $this.on('click.temp', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Using an `.off()` doesn't seem to cancel the original handler on the class because it is attached to the class not the element.

I think I've partly answered my question with `e.stopPropagation()`, but it's still not quite working and I'm not convinced I'm going about this the best way :)

Note: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708450/how-to-disable-jquery-keypress-event-for-just-one-element) relates to the idea but does not use `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than adding and removing handlers for the inputs on the fly, I'd stick with delegated event handlers like you're already doing in the click handler that *creates* the inputs:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.test', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.removeClass("test")
         .html("<input type='text' value='" + $this.text() + "'/><input id='me' value='Submit' type='button'>");
});

$('#container').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        new_text = $this.prev().val();
    $this.parent().addClass("test")
                  .html(new_text);
});
```

On click of a '.test' div replace its contents with inputs like you were doing, but also remove the "test" class so that further clicks on the div won't do anything (for the moment).

On click of a submit button change the div back to just show the text, and add the class back again so that the previous click handler takes effect again.

Note: I've changed your buttons from `type="submit"` to `type="button"` because they're not actually used to submit a form.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4vmQ4/5/

Comment: I confess I prefer delegated event handlers. I tried using `<button...` but forgot about `type="button"`; the former creates a pretty blue button :)  The `id="me"` is also redundant in your code (and mine, too).

Comment: Could I not just use a class for the button? It wasn't working, but it should in theory, no?

Comment: Yes, you could use a class if you mean you want to use that as the selector in the second `.on()` function, like `$('#container').on('click', '.yourButtonClass', ...` - of course you'd add the class in the code that creates the button. There should be no problem using a `<button>` element instead of `<input>`, in fact here's a version that does so: http://jsfiddle.net/4vmQ4/6/. I forgot to mention that the `id="me"` is not only redundant since it's never used but _incorrect_ since if you edit multiple lines at once you'll have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: Yes, the `id="me"` was just a hack to try and get my original fiddle working. It wasn't picking up my class handler (and still isn't). I'm going to use your solution in practice, although I need to create a new class akin to `test` for the purpose :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it simply like following:

```
function testClick() {

    var $this = $(this),
        text = $this.text();

    // you have to off the click like this
    $('#container').off('click', '.test');
    
    $this.html(
        "<input class='text' type='text' value='" + text + "'/><input class='submit' value='Submit' type='submit'>"
    );

    $this.find('.submit').on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var new_text = $this.find('input.text').val();
        $this.html(new_text);
        $('#container').on('click', '.test', testClick); // again on click
    });
}

$('#container').on('click', '.test', testClick);
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/qG7WP/3/)**

#### You can separate the submit event like following:

```
function testClick() {

    var $this = $(this),
        text = $this.text();

    // you have to off the click like this
    $('#container').off('click', '.test');

    $this.html("<input class='text' type='text' value='" + text + "'/><input class='submit' value='Submit' type='submit'>");
}

$('#container').on('click', '.submit', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var new_text = $(this).prev('input.text').val();
    $(this).parent().html(new_text);
    $('#container').on('click', '.test', testClick); // again on click
});

$('#container').on('click', '.test', testClick);
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/qG7WP/7/)**

Comment: Yes, this works nicely. It only allows one comment to be edited at a time, and although that's not what I had in mind, it might be better that way anyway :)

Comment: @Nick `click.testClick` means a custom `namaspace` event and in this case I don't need that..

Comment: Yes, my mistake :)  I realised and deleted that bit of my comment. I'm now experimenting with having the `.submit` handler separate to the function `testClick`.

Answer (score 1):

I basically restructured your code so that the events are turned on and off in the same manner.

Updated Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qZVzY/6/

**Updated Code**

`onClickReadMode` - is the event handler when the div is clicked while in read mode

`onClickEditMode` - is the event handler when the div is clicked while in edit mode

```
function onClickReadMode(_elem) {
    console.log('onClickReadMode');
    var $this = _elem, text = $this.text();
    $this.html("<input class='text' type='text' value='" + text + "'/><input class='.submit' value='Submit' type='submit'>");
    _elem.off('click.before');
    _elem.on('click.after', function() {
        onClickEditMode($(this));
    });
    _elem.find('.text').on('click.stopevent', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });
}

function onClickEditMode(_elem) {
    console.log('onClickEditMode');
    var $this = _elem;
    var new_text = $this.find('input').val();
    $this.html(new_text);
    _elem.off('click.after');
    _elem.on('click.before', function() {
        onClickReadMode($(this));
    });
}

$('.test').on('click.before', function (e) {
    onClickReadMode($(this));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  I streamlined the code a little so I could read it better at http://jsfiddle.net/dSmrN/ :)  There's a hitch, though. Try this (on your original code): Click top comment into edit. Click bottom into edit. Submit bottom. Submit top! Submit top again!! Any ideas?

Comment: Check out the updated demo and code! I suppose this works as intended